# Volatile keyword for thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic

I have the below code:

```
public class Foo {
  private volatile Map<String, String> map;

  public Foo() {
    refresh();
  }

  public void refresh() {
    map = getData();
  }

  public boolean isPresent(String id) {
    return map.containsKey(id);
  }

  public String getName(String id) {
    return map.get(id);
  }

  private Map<String, String> getData() {
    // logic
  }

}
```

- Is the above code thread safe or do I need to add `synchronized` or mutexes in there? If it's not thread safe, please clarify why.

Also, I've read that one should use `AtomicReference` instead of this, but in the source of the `AtomicReference` class, I can see that the field used to hold the value is volatile (along with a few convenience methods).

- Is there a specific reason to use `AtomicReference` instead?

I've read multiple answer related to this but the concept of volatile still confuses me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should use `ConcurrentHashMap` for intance. volatile  (or atomic reference) here is useless in this case.

Comment: its not thread safe, although the reference to the Map class is volatile, the data are not

Comment: @nafas But I am never modifying the map object itself. I am always updating the reference.

Comment: @Kayaman - What operation will not be thread safe and why? can you please clarify?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh if no modification is done to the map, then there is no need to worry about anything. you don't even need volatile

Comment: @GurwinderSingh read only is thread safe

Comment: @nafas - But thread safety is not just about atomicity - the updates should be timely visible to other threads as well, right? Doesn't volatile help in that regard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not modifying the contents of `map` (except inside of `refresh()` when creating it), then there are no visibility issues in the code.

It's still possible to do `isPresent()`, `refresh()`, `getName()` (if no outside synchronization is used) and end up with `isPresent()==true` and `getName()==null`.

Comment: You are right. That can happen. What do you think would be the best way to fix that? I am think that just use `getName()` and see if that is null (I'll never have null in names).

Comment: One option would be to add `synchronized` to `refresh()`, and whenever you're doing `isPresent()/getName()` you would synchronize on your `Foo`. However since `getName()` returns `null` if not present, I'm not sure why you would write `isPresent()/getName()` combos. Then again, I don't know what you're trying to do with your code.

Comment: If I omit the `isPresent` method, do I still need synchronization?

Comment: No. It would only be required if you wanted to call `isPresent()/getName()` in an atomic fashion, but as I stated it seems unnecessary.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: You sure its unnecessary? As far as I understood the memory model with the new reference might be under construction while the other `Thread` already wants to do read operations on it. It will use the old copy of it.

Comment: @MuratK. the `volatile` is necessary, but additional `synchronization` isn't.

Answer (score 2):

A class is "thread safe" if it does the right thing when it is used by multiple threads at the same time.  There is no way to tell whether a class is thread safe unless you can say what "the right thing" means, and especially, what "the right thing when used by multiple threads" means.

What is the right thing if thread A calls `foo.isPresent("X")` and it returns true, and then thread B calls `foo.refresh()`, and then thread A calls `foo.getName("X")`?

If you are going to claim "thread safety", then you must be very explicit about what the caller should expect in cases like that.

Answer (score 0):

Volatile is only useful in this scenario to update the value immediately. It doesn't really make the code by itself thread-safe.

But because you've stated in your comment, you only update the reference and because the reference-switch is atomic, your code will be thread-safe.(from the given code)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly and your comments - your class `Foo` holds a `Map` in which only the reference should be updated e.g. a whole new `Map` added instead of mutating it. If this is the premise:

It does not make any difference if you declare it as `volatile` or not. Every read/write operation in Java is atomic itself. You will never see a half transaction on these operations. See the [JLS 17.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7)

> 17.7. Non-Atomic Treatment of double and long
>
> For the purposes of the Java programming language memory model, a single write to a non-volatile long or double value is treated as two separate writes: one to each 32-bit half. This can result in a situation where a thread sees the first 32 bits of a 64-bit value from one write, and the second 32 bits from another write.
>
> Writes and reads of volatile long and double values are always atomic.
>
> **Writes to and reads of references are always atomic, regardless of whether they are implemented as 32-bit or 64-bit values.**
>
> Some implementations may find it convenient to divide a single write action on a 64-bit long or double value into two write actions on adjacent 32-bit values. For efficiency's sake, this behavior is implementation-specific; an implementation of the Java Virtual Machine is free to perform writes to long and double values atomically or in two parts.
>
> Implementations of the Java Virtual Machine are encouraged to avoid splitting 64-bit values where possible. Programmers are encouraged to declare shared 64-bit values as volatile or synchronize their programs correctly to avoid possible complications.

EDIT: Although the top statement still stands as it is - for thread safety it's necessary to add `volatile` to reflect the immediate update on different `Threads` to reflect the reference update. The behavior of a `Thread` is to make local copy of it while with `volatile` it will do a  `happens-before relationship` in other words the `Threads` will have the same state of the `Map`.

Comment: But thread safety is not just about atomicity - the updates should be timely visible to other threads as well, right? Doesn't volatile help in that regard?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh You are right. I read more into the memory model and while the reference update is atomic - it's not thread-safe since the other `Thread` may already have a older copy of it while the new one is getting constructed. With volatile there is the happens-before relationship which prevents this.